# Heroku app takes too long to load at times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app is basic (1 dyno, 20MB slug size) and some of the pages take too long to load at times. Using Firebug, I've observed that most of the times the pages load within 3-4 sec but sometimes it takes more than a minute for the page to load (both data points are when the cache on the browser is cleared). The basic html response was within 500ms and the main component of the time was downloading a png image (17kb image) for which the wait time (after sending request) was more than a min. I cannot understand why this would be the case.

I am using Yslow to analyze the entire page (gave a B grade) and I think this has something to do with Heroku taking long to send images at times.

I have referred to the question - [Why are my basic Heroku apps taking two seconds to load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606190/why-are-my-basic-heroku-apps-taking-2-seconds-to-load)

As suggested in the answers, I have put a simple cron task in heroku that accesses the homepage every hour through a URI GET request.

What could I do to improve the speed?

I am considering the following things:
1. Move images to a CDN
2. Put a get expires header as given in http://upstre.am/blog/tag/heroku/

Comment: Is your sight published somewhere so that we could look at it?

Comment: Is that 1 *free* dyno, or 1 *paid* dyno?

Answer (score 2):

> I have put a simple cron task in heroku that accesses the homepage every hour through a URI GET request.

From what you are describing you are using Heroku cron job to ping your app. Unfortunately this will not work as you have to use an external ping service such as [Pingdom](http://pingdom.com).

**Update**: seems like external ping services like Pingdom no longer works either..

Answer (score 0):

Heroku 'idles' dynos if they aren't used for more than 30min I believe.  This means you'll need more than 1 web dyno if you want to keep the app active and ready to load at any time.  Worker dynos are never idled.

Basically just set your app to 2 web dynos.