# Rails. First request too slow, times out, the next ones are faster

Tags: ruby, caching, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

I'm developing a rails application. After pushing the git on Heroku without trouble, the app show an error "request time out" inside the webbrowser.

If i'm re-trying 1 minute after, the app display the page very quikly on the webbrowser.

**CONFIGURATION**

Find below my configuration

- Rails 5.1.2
- psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1

The main info inside the gem file:

```
ruby '2.2.6'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'

gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'

gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
```

Heroku

```
Standard-2X dynos, Shared, 1 GB RAM

Heroku Postgres :: Brown

Memcached Cloud :free

Papertrail :free

STANDARD PLAN
```

**LOG**

The log of the first very long request ( notice that I restart the server before the test to reproduce the problem that append every morning at the first request)

```
Aug 25 03:28:15 myapplication app/web.1:  => Booting Puma 
Aug 25 03:28:15 myapplication app/web.1:  => Rails 5.1.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:41080 
Aug 25 03:28:15 myapplication app/web.1:  => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options 
Aug 25 03:28:15 myapplication app/web.1:  [4] Puma starting in cluster mode... 
Aug 25 03:28:15 myapplication app/web.1:  [4] * Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.2.6-p396), codename: Private Caller 
Aug 25 03:28:15 myapplication app/web.1:  [4] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5 
Aug 25 03:28:15 myapplication app/web.1:  [4] * Environment: production 
Aug 25 03:28:15 myapplication app/web.1:  [4] * Process workers: 2 
Aug 25 03:28:15 myapplication app/web.1:  [4] * Preloading application 
Aug 25 03:28:15 myapplication app/web.1:  [4] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:41080 
Aug 25 03:28:15 myapplication app/web.1:  [4] Use Ctrl-C to stop 
Aug 25 03:28:15 myapplication app/web.1:  [4] - Worker 0 (pid: 6) booted, phase: 0 
Aug 25 03:28:15 myapplication app/web.1:  [4] - Worker 1 (pid: 19) booted, phase: 0 
Aug 25 03:28:15 myapplication heroku/web.1:  State changed from starting to up 
Aug 25 03:28:37 myapplication app/heroku-postgres:  source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BROWN sample#current_transaction=2339 sample#db_size=25066008bytes sample#tables=21 sample#active-connections=2 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0.99931 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.996 sample#load-avg-1m=0 sample#load-avg-5m=0 sample#load-avg-15m=0 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.057733 sample#memory-total=4044984kB sample#memory-free=1550168kB sample#memory-cached=1945532kB sample#memory-postgres=16880kB 
Aug 25 03:30:38 myapplication app/heroku-postgres:  source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BROWN sample#current_transaction=2339 sample#db_size=25066008bytes sample#tables=21 sample#active-connections=2 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0.99931 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.996 sample#load-avg-1m=0 sample#load-avg-5m=0 sample#load-avg-15m=0 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.029687 sample#memory-total=4044984kB sample#memory-free=1550000kB sample#memory-cached=1945544kB sample#memory-postgres=16880kB 
Aug 25 03:31:39 myapplication app/heroku-postgres:  source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BROWN sample#current_transaction=2339 sample#db_size=25066008bytes sample#tables=21 sample#active-connections=2 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0.99931 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.996 sample#load-avg-1m=0 sample#load-avg-5m=0 sample#load-avg-15m=0 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.029687 sample#memory-total=4044984kB sample#memory-free=1549940kB sample#memory-cached=1945564kB sample#memory-postgres=16880kB 
Aug 25 03:32:38 myapplication app/heroku-postgres:  source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BROWN sample#current_transaction=2339 sample#db_size=25066008bytes sample#tables=21 sample#active-connections=2 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0.99931 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.996 sample#load-avg-1m=0 sample#load-avg-5m=0 sample#load-avg-15m=0 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.029687 sample#memory-total=4044984kB sample#memory-free=1550284kB sample#memory-cached=1945568kB sample#memory-postgres=16880kB 
Aug 25 03:33:39 myapplication app/heroku-postgres: source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BROWN sample#current_transaction=2339 sample#db_size=25066008bytes sample#tables=21 sample#active-connections=2 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0.99931 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.996 sample#load-avg-1m=0 sample#load-avg-5m=0 sample#load-avg-15m=0 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.030191 sample#memory-total=4044984kB sample#memory-free=1550128kB sample#memory-cached=1945580kB sample#memory-postgres=16880kB 
Aug 25 03:33:51 myapplication heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myapplication.herokuapp.com request_id=afa5c118-7319-4b9b-a945-60ed57a63062 fwd="90.87.43.215" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=72ms status=301 bytes=371 protocol=https 
Aug 25 03:33:51 myapplication app/web.1: I, [2017-08-25T10:33:50.584824 #19]  INFO -- : [afa5c118-7319-4b9b-a945-60ed57a63062] Started GET "/" for 90.87.43.215 at 2017-08-25 10:33:50 +0000 
Aug 25 03:33:51 myapplication app/web.1: I, [2017-08-25T10:33:50.665212 #19]  INFO -- : [6db31a1a-39a5-4a8f-9ba1-cf35ceae5f61] Started GET "/projets/new" for 90.87.43.215 at 2017-08-25 10:33:50 +0000 
Aug 25 03:33:51 myapplication app/web.1: I, [2017-08-25T10:33:50.670054 #19]  INFO -- : [6db31a1a-39a5-4a8f-9ba1-cf35ceae5f61] Processing by ProjetsController#new as HTML 
Aug 25 03:33:51 myapplication app/web.1: D, [2017-08-25T10:33:50.783930 #19] DEBUG -- : [6db31a1a-39a5-4a8f-9ba1-cf35ceae5f61]   User Load (3.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]] 
Aug 25 03:33:51 myapplication app/web.1: D, [2017-08-25T10:33:50.928475 #19] DEBUG -- : [6db31a1a-39a5-4a8f-9ba1-cf35ceae5f61]   Regleconfiguration Load (3.4ms)  SELECT  "regleconfigurations".* FROM "regleconfigurations" ORDER BY "regleconfigurations"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]] 
Aug 25 03:33:51 myapplication app/web.1: D, [2017-08-25T10:33:50.955570 #19] DEBUG -- : [6db31a1a-39a5-4a8f-9ba1-cf35ceae5f61]   Tarifoptionbt Load (3.2ms)  SELECT "tarifoptionbts".* FROM "tarifoptionbts" 
Aug 25 03:33:51 myapplication app/web.1: I, [2017-08-25T10:33:50.989799 #19]  INFO -- : [6db31a1a-39a5-4a8f-9ba1-cf35ceae5f61]   Rendering projets/new.html.erb within layouts/application 
Aug 25 03:34:21 myapplication heroku/router: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/projets/new" host=myapplication.herokuapp.com request_id=6db31a1a-39a5-4a8f-9ba1-cf35ceae5f61 fwd="90.87.43.215" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https 
Aug 25 03:34:39 myapplication app/heroku-postgres: source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BROWN sample#current_transaction=2339 sample#db_size=25066008bytes sample#tables=21 sample#active-connections=3 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0.99931 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.996 sample#load-avg-1m=0 sample#load-avg-5m=0 sample#load-avg-15m=0 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.029687 sample#memory-total=4044984kB sample#memory-free=1547512kB sample#memory-cached=1945596kB sample#memory-postgres=20036kB 
Aug 25 03:35:37 myapplication app/web.1: I, [2017-08-25T10:35:37.131381 #19]  INFO -- : [6db31a1a-39a5-4a8f-9ba1-cf35ceae5f61]   Rendered projets/_etapebar.html.erb (106132.4ms)
```

[.....] render 30 partial view

```
Aug 25 03:35:38 myapplication app/web.1: I, [2017-08-25T10:35:37.495939 #19]  INFO -- : [6db31a1a-39a5-4a8f-9ba1-cf35ceae5f61] Completed 200 OK in 106826ms (Views: 106499.5ms | ActiveRecord: 50.2ms)
```

If I render a second time the same view I get this log:

```
Aug 25 05:42:45 myapplication app/web.1: I, [2017-08-25T12:42:44.339695 #19]  INFO -- : [9c38a6b8-73d4-4e31-9ac3-df2ec8b21049] Started GET "/projets/new" for 90.87.43.215 at 2017-08-25 12:42:44 +0000 
Aug 25 05:42:45 myapplication app/web.1: I, [2017-08-25T12:42:44.341197 #19]  INFO -- : [9c38a6b8-73d4-4e31-9ac3-df2ec8b21049] Processing by ProjetsController#new as HTML 
Aug 25 05:42:45 myapplication app/web.1: D, [2017-08-25T12:42:44.348612 #19] DEBUG -- : [9c38a6b8-73d4-4e31-9ac3-df2ec8b21049]   User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]] 
Aug 25 05:42:45 myapplication app/web.1: I, [2017-08-25T12:42:44.351579 #19]  INFO -- : [9c38a6b8-73d4-4e31-9ac3-df2ec8b21049] Completed 200 OK in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

The application jump from a 106 second to serve a first request ( that's create a Heroku error) to a very short time in a second render

**ASSET**

Log show that the second call get asset from request.

In my app, on each page, I load the js of the current controller:

in application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag controller.controller_name if TarifsDynamique::Application.assets.find_asset("#{controller.controller_name}.css") %>
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] if TarifsDynamique::Application.assets.find_asset("#{controller.controller_name}.js") %>
```

and in from application.js and .css, i remove //=require .

and in asset.rb , I add

```
 Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["#{controller}.js", "#{controller}.css"]
```

whith all the controller.

It's work find ( in devvellpoment and in production after the first call).

but when, I try to

```
$Heroku run assets:precompile
```

I got this error

```
Running rake assets:precompile on ⬢ myapplication... up, run.9829 (Standard-1X)
Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
...
```

**CACHE**

I try to add cache to speed up the first page

- cache action inside the controler:

  ```
  class ProjetsController < ApplicationController

    caches_action :new, :edit
  ```
- cache the view: new.html.erb

  ```
  <%= render 'form', projet: @projet, cached: true %>
  ```
- active cache inside production.rb

  ```
  Rails.application.configure do

      config.cache_classes = true
  ```

**NO IDEA**

I have no more idea
If you get an idea , its will be so helpfull !

Thanks.

**[EDIT]**
**SOLUTION**

Hi, 
I finally found what's going on !
I have 50 images to compile in the asset folder.
Even if I precompile them, at the first request after a long sleep, Rails precompile them again that take tomany time.

1- I move image on amason S3, 
2- change image_tag to image_static_tag
3- create a image_static_tag helper that serve static file from s3
4- redeploy the app and now everything is ok !!

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606190/why-are-my-basic-heroku-apps-taking-two-seconds-to-load. Sounds like your app is booting on the first request which is why it takes so long. That's what the logs are indicating as well.

Comment: Yeah, I think the simple answer is probably that you need to increase your Dynos.

Comment: @Puhlze : thanks for yours answer. The server doesn't restart . I restart the server to reproduce the bug. If I don't the server response is very until the next morning. I have a standard price plan. I understand that whith this plan , server never sleep ( like hobby plan). I updated the information

Comment: @BrandonElder. thanks for your add. I already get a STANDARD plan. https://www.heroku.com/pricing, wich one you advise me ?