# Deploying JAVA war to dynamic website performance issue

Tags: java, android, performance, heroku

I have built a java program within an android app that parses some data from an online website. This data is to be used from the app to show the content(organized) to the user. I tried to optimize my code as much as I could but there's not much I can do since it's a lot of data. So what I did instead was deploying the java program on HEROKU and let the server side do the work and give the result in a simple html which I can easily parse with no major delay. The thing is that this worked out pretty fine. I got a high increase in performance yet with one little problem. When I open the app for the first time in say 2 days it results to be a lot slower, but on the second run just after that it seems to be a lot faster. Now I am guessing that the HEROKU server works on some cache-like way in that the least recent run dynamic web sites get no priority until a request comes from the client side, considering that in 2,3 consequent runs I get a very high increase in performance. Now, my question is, is there a way I can sort of "give priority" to my HEROKU java program or is there another free dynamic web site that allows you to deploy a war and presents  no such performance issues. To some it might seem as a no big deal. In particular I get performance increase of say from 6 seconds to 2 seconds which is actually quite a big deal since app users usually do not tolerate such kinds of delays.

Comment: It's more likely an issue with poor programming than with Heroku. Why don't you turn this question into an actual question instead of a wall of unrelated text? We can't just guess what your application does and magically give suggestions for that.

Comment: @nbokmans I'm actually getting from 6300 milliseconds to 300 milliseconds which is an increase by nearly 21 times in performance which I think is quite significant. Nearly the same thing happens if I try to run it on localhost. So I guess my code is fine. Just looking for some alternatives in that I am not way too experienced with deploying dynamic websites online.

Comment: @nbokmans and as I can see there are also other people with the same problem around here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606190/why-are-my-basic-heroku-apps-taking-two-seconds-to-load)  just looking for a workaround to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku puts free apps to sleep. The first request after it sleeps will restart the app, which means you have to wait longer.

For more info see [Heroku's sleeping policy for Free dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping).