# Why is heroku so sluggish?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I deployed a very simple nodejs app using expressjs. It has a few routes and static content with no database connection or anything. The problem is the ridiculously slow response of service. This is the link:

[nodejs app deployed on heroku](https://gentle-plateau-54294.herokuapp.com/)

It literally takes 10 seconds to load up for the first time, though faster in next requests obviously because of cache. Do I need to add paid dyno or add-on to make it faster?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my basic Heroku apps taking two seconds to load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606190/why-are-my-basic-heroku-apps-taking-two-seconds-to-load)

Comment: You can use this to keep the app awake: http://kaffeine.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is running on free dyno, it goes to sleep when unused for 30 mins. You could find the information [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours).

You could verify the sleep by checking the logs `heroku logs --tail`.

You could add additional dyno other than free type to make it not to sleep. [Dyno Types](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types)

Comment: Thanks for your help